# How to add a Text to res-drawable in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

Now I want to add a Text ( like Image Description ) in drawable file.

Example I want to add Description "eraser_1" at top of a textView by drawableTop.....

Anyone can help me ?

[This is what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF0AZ.png). I dont want to use more a Framework

Comment: just make `TextView`, set text to it and place in your layout. drawables made in XML don't have option for placing text

Comment: @snachmsm  i look forward to drawable_.xml contains text "eraser ", and i set to any TextView by setCompoundDrawables( , , , ). Maybe it impossible ?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use this code for text over drawable.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/examplepic"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="example"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can replace that textView by .xml ? . I want to use drawableTop ?

Comment: can you share any kind of image which you want to do

Comment: I just edited the question . My image added . Sound like "note" in SUDOKU game